# Why do people use a separate program for raw image processing?

Tags: raw, photo-editing

There are programs that are advertised as raw image editors such as Corel Aftershot Pro and there are programs advertised as image editors such as Corel Paintshop pro. If I understood well, people first do some editing on their raw images (using Aftershot or adobe raw) and then import them into another program for further processing such as Photoshop or Paintshop.

Why is the workflow like this? Why don't people directly process their raw images in Paintshop pro for example?
To me it seems their are software specifically designed for raw image editing and other software for further processing.
Is it just the marketing strategy of companies to divide their software into pieces to make more profit? or Are there some limitation about what someone can do with raw images before converting/importing them into another software?

Comment: This is really a subjective thing, what software you use will be down to the user and with so many options it's hard to really comment. For myself I use Lightroom and Photoshop - I generally stick with LR as my edits aren't extremely big, just bringing up whites or making a picture warmer - If I want to remove something from a picture or do more editing I'll move to Photoshop which is more powerful but far more effort.

Comment: Can you do whatever you do with your raw file in Lightroom in Photoshop too? I do not know, but I have the impression that Photoshop is more limited than Lightroom in editing raw files. If this is the case, then why is it like this? Is it decision of Adobe to make more profit or are there limitations on how much edit can be done on a raw image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we even need RAW-specific editing software?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49799/why-do-we-even-need-raw-specific-editing-software)

Comment: Adobe charges 9.99/month for LR + PS. They charge 19.99/month for a single application. Your premise that using two programs is more expensive than one appears to be incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dedicated applications to process RAW files exist because some things are best done from RAW (like noise reduction) before conversion to an RGB format (because RAW are not RGB formats) and because there are many specialist algorithms that can be applied to RAW to reduce artifacts from demosaicing in special situations.

In particular noise is "spread out" by demosaicing from RAW formats (which all images start from even if the camera does not explicitly support RAW files).  Once this is done you cannot undo the effect.  So noise reduction needs (ideally) to be done as a first step in RAW development.

As you cannot undo RAW conversion to an RGB format, you cannot undo the effects of noise and artifacts in images as well as you can from RAW.

Now for most people this is unnecessary as they'll frankly manage fine with the JPEG straight from camera.  But for some people who want to squeeze every last detail from an image the extra detail of dedicated RAW developer applications is worth it.

Note that something like the Camera Raw plugin in Photoshop is essentially an application that sits between Photoshop and the RAW file.

In general there is a software philosophy at work which tries to make separate units or applications to handle specific tasks.  This lets developer isolate tasks and optimize them without complicating the software development process in undesirable ways.

> Is it just the marketing strategy of companies to divide their software into pieces to make more profit?

Blame your camera companies.

The camera makers seem to feel that changing RAW file formats with every new model makes some kind of sense and, not only do they not make the formats public (making it very hard for software developers) but they've even been known to encrypt parts of RAW files.  They could use a common format that would make software development easier for all concerned, but they don't.

As software development costs money and as the makers of software have to at least break even, it's not surprising that commercial software that reads RAW files costs more money for new versions.

Comment: Agreed. The only thing I would add is that it actually helps workflow efficiency to have two programs. If you only care about 1 or 2 shots at a time, you don't notice. When you have 100+ wedding shots to get ready for print, it helps a ton to focus your work in stages with whatever software is designed for the stage you're on at any given time.

Comment: I've wanted to understand this myself - I understand the principles of using RAW (and I do), I shoot in RAW and then bring that into LR as a DNG. Would it make any difference to import with Camera Raw first?

Comment: @dazzathedrummer - here's a pretty decent workflow comparison: http://www.earthboundlight.com/phototips/are-camera-raw-and-lightroom-the-same.html

Comment: *"The camera makers seem to feel that changing RAW file formats with every new model makes some kind of sense"* Different sensor designs require different demosaicing algorithms, even if the raw data is in the same type of raw format.

Comment: @MichaelClark I don't think this is true unless you mean different types of filter array (like Bayer and X-trans).  But most systems (even Fuji's old tilted arrays) are variations on a basic pattern.  But for Bayer sensor (the vast majority) the same demosaic approach is used for them all, AFAIK.  Some parameters change, but these could be made available if the makers wanted to, which just makes life difficult for everyone to no-ones advantage.  That's my reading of the code I've seen, anyway.

Comment: Every sensor has its own characteristics that must be taken into account when demosaicing the raw data collected by it. Ignoring those "parameters" as you call them would lead to inaccurate conversion. That is why early adopters of new cameras usually have to wait a few weeks before third party programs such as ACR can handle raw files from the new camera model.

Comment: @MichaelClark That's the point I'm making.  Those parameters have to be determined by third parties instead of being supplied by the makers in a standard format (e.g. in Metadata) attached to every file.  The issue is the makers being so reluctant to cooperate with software makers, not the process itself, which is well understood.

Comment: The need for the changes is due to the different physical characteristics of the sensors, not due to the manufacturers desire to make it difficult for third parties to create products that work with their products.

Comment: Why should the manufacturers worry about providing more metadata when the vast majority of third party applications (cough, Adobe, cough) already ignore the greater parts of the maker notes currently included in the EXIF info? They're not even leveraging what is already available. The manufacturers' own raw converters certainly do take advantage of that info.

Comment: @MichaelClark This doesn't fee like a productive discussion, but you might consider that many people seem to prefer the third party applications for RAW conversion (like Adobe's stuff, DxO, RawTherapee, Dark Table, etc.) and not the camera makers (who, IMO as a former software engineer) produce not very good software.  And it's hard to leverage info when some makers even encrypt the data to prevent you using it !  Some makers, particularly Nikon, are so anti-third party as to be practically hostile.

Comment: @StephenG Nikon actually shares their demosaicing algorithms with Adobe and DxO, unlike Canon.

Answer (score 2):

Most programs such as Photoshop or Paintshop Pro are set up to handle a single image at a time.

Most raw converters such as Lightroom (which also uses Adobe Camera Raw under the hood, just like Photoshop does when dealing with a raw image file) are set up to handle large numbers of images and apply the same processing to many of them at once.

In addition to raw conversion, many raw processing programs, including Lightroom, also offer organization and tagging of large numbers of images as well.

Comment: Good point. Another use case for batch mode is if you're working on an underpowered computer. You can queue up processing of a bunch of images and go make lunch while the actual processing happens.

Comment: @JosephRogers Isn't that what "... and apply the same processing to many of them at once" means?

Comment: not entirely, that reads as "I took a bunch of shots in similar conditions on similar settings so I know they all need + half a stop and this profile". I'm talking about setting up a bunch of individual shots with potentially very different settings, but delaying the actual processing until you don't need your computer for half an hour. My old laptop (core duo, 2GB RAM) would grind to a halt processing DSLR images but was quite happy to run RawTherapee with the processing turned off to make a queue, then process over dinner time.

Comment: to be clear your use case is completely valid too and probably the first thing that comes to mind when you think of batch mode, I'm just suggesting another related use which is similar but not quite the same

Comment: @JosephRogers You're not actually *applying* anything until you do the batch processing.

Comment: exactly, but the settings you apply don't have to be the same

Comment: "same processing" = "convert and export all images from raw NEF to JPEG" or "convert and export all images from raw CR2 to 16-bit TIFF." It doesn't mean the specific settings for each image have to be exactly the same.

Comment: If I add the same "recipe" (specific set of settings) to multiple images during the editing process I don't consider that "applying the same processing."

Comment: In that case we are talking about the same thing, but I doubt I'm the only one who will read your words the way I did. Regardless, I +1ed your answer